# Substring + IndexOf to get specific portions of String

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof

Let's say I have this code:

```java
String str = ""Name":"John","LastName":"Joshua"";
```

And I want to get the name of the person and his last name.
How would I go about it?
I know I'd need to use Substring and IndexOf, but not exactly sure how
to exactly tell tell the program to search for:
"Name":
and then print John without the "".
Same goes for LastName.

Comment: Is this supposed to be JSON you are receiving?  Kinda confused on how somebody runs into such data

Comment: Also, what you posted wouldn't compile.

Comment: @JBNizet I know it was just an example and it's from the internet. RobOhRob

Comment: The thing is, if we can't know what you're supposed to parse because what you post isn't correct, and is a random thing you found on the internet, we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, for java declaring a string or at least the way I know is done by doing `String name = "John" , lastName = "Joshua";`
 then to print it you can do something like `System.out.print(name + " " + lastName);` hopefully this is what you are asking. This might need to go under something other than java though...

Comment: Ok so it was just an example, I know the String is not right.
Let's say it appears on a web page: "Name":"John","LastName":"Joshua".
How would you go about detecting where Name is and what the name is and where it ends? same for last name.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to write `String str = "\"Name\":\"John\",\"Surname\":\"Joshua\""";` because " is reserved in Java. You can only write quotation marks in a String if you write a backslash before it so that the complier does not interpret it. I assume you want to edit a JSON file; there are many libraries to do this (just use Google). 
Otherwise, you can try using the `String.split();` method to split the string by " or by "name".

Comment: If it is not JSON, it might be a better idea to wrap the string in curly braces and parse it as JSON, because there are many cases where String.split would fail (e.g. commas inside names).

Comment: that depends on what string you split it with. But you're right about that.